# Check entry exists in sqlite3 python

Tags: python-3.x, database, sqlite

I checked some similar posts, but don't get my answer.

I want to check if specific username is in database or not.

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect("session.db")
c = con.cursor()
a1 = 'jack'
c.execute("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT username FROM User WHERE username=?)", (a1))
if c.fetchone():
    print("Found!")

else:
    print("Not found...")
```

[image]

Comment: What is the current output from your Python script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your code a bit like this-

```
c.execute("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT username FROM User WHERE username=?)", (a1,))
```

Notice the comma after `a1`. Without this change the code should throw an error like `Incorrect number of bindings supplied` as only `a1` (in your case value `jack`) will be treated as 4 different parameter provided to `c.execute()`. Turning it to tuple will bind the whole string `jack` to the appropriate placeholder.

After that check the result like -

```
found, = c.fetchone()
# found will be 1 in case the entry is present
if found: 
    print("Found")
else:
    print("Not found")
```

`c.fetchone()` returns a tuple. In your case tuple with one element indicating whether the entry exists or not (1 if present, 0 otherwise)

Comment: ok but don't check entry is found or not found , any entry say Found

Answer (score 2):

Your script has one obvious problem with it, namely that you are *not* actually passing a valid Python tuple to the call to `execute()`.  Instead, you are passing a single string variable.  You should be passing `(a,)`, with a trailing comma, to tell Python that you intend this to mean a tuple.

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect("session.db")
c = con.cursor()
a1 = 'jack'
c.execute("SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM User WHERE username = ?)", (a1,))
if c.fetchone():
    print("Found!")
else:
    print("Not found...")
```

To be clear here, `('jack')` will be interpreted as a string, while `('jack',)` will be interpreted as a tuple.

Comment: username jack is found but other not found say found